# What does this mean? Why is it required? cur_row, cur_col = cur_path[-1]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im looking at some code for BFS traversal of maze in python. First time writing with python, I want to understand what the reason for cur_row, cur_col = cur_path[-1] is, specifically why [-1] is needed

```
def bfs(maze):
    queue = []
    visited = set()
    queue.append([maze.getStart()])
    while queue:
        cur_path = queue.pop(0)
        cur_row, cur_col = cur_path[-1]
        if (cur_row, cur_col) in visited:
            continue
        visited.add((cur_row, cur_col))
        if maze.isObjective(cur_row, cur_col):
            return cur_path, len(visited)
        for item in maze.getNeighbors(cur_row, cur_col):
            if item not in visited:
                queue.append(cur_path + [item])
    return [], 0
```

Comment: Hi! because you want to pick last element from curr_path everytime.

Comment: As a first-time Python user, you should start with learning the language foundations.

Comment: assign `(x, *y, z) = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` , then print and check what values each of those variables `x`,`y` & `z` have , also assign `a,b,c =y` check what values does `a`,`b` & `c` has. also check what is `y[-1]` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, a negative index indicates 'counting from the end'.

So, `some_list[-1]` means "the last element of `some_list`", `some_list[-2]` is the element before that, etc.

What is happening when you see `cur_row, cur_col = cur_path[-1]`, is that the last element of `cur_path` is taken and apparently that's a tuple of two values, which are then assigned (this is called a 'spread') to the two variables `cur_row` and `cur_col`.

For example:

```
pairs = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
a, b = pairs[-1]
```

After this, `a` will be `5` and `b` will be `6`.

People posting comments that you should learn the basics are right, but although Python can be deceptively simple at times, it's also very good at allowing you to write very short statements that require a bit of understanding of the language. This is a good example, as both negative indexing and spreading aren't features common to most programming languages.

Comment: thank you so much! yeah I definitely need to learn the basics, but a class I am taking is taught in Python so I am just trying to learn as I go. thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome - please accept the answer, if you think it answered your question (hit the check mark), so that the question is listed as answered.